# Get the warning when upgrade mysql 5.7 to 8.0 on bionic!

Tags: apt, upgrade, mysql

I already installed MySQL of client and server with 5.7 version.

When I check MySQL packages available :

```
$ sudo apt search mysql
mysql-client/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  MySQL Client meta package depending on latest version

mysql-client-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  MySQL database client binaries

mysql-client-core-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  MySQL database core client binaries

mysql-server/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  MySQL Server meta package depending on latest version

mysql-server-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  MySQL database server binaries and system database setup

mysql-server-core-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  MySQL database server binaries
```

I try to upgrade MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0 version, with following steps:

**1. Download the Repository**

```
$ wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

**2. installing the package and configuring**

```
$ sudo gdebi mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done

Auto configuration for MySQL APT Repo.
 MySQL is a fast, stable and true multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database
 server. SQL (Structured Query Language) is the most popular database query
 language in the world. The main goals of MySQL are speed, robustness and
 ease of use.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-apt-config.
(Reading database ... 232093 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
OK
```

How can I fix that the warnings and update/upgrade all my databases? Asking because I forgot to backup my databases with `mysqldump` query!

Comment: I don't see any errors in that output - just one warning. And I don't see anything in that output that prevents your from backing up your databases.

Comment: is my databases on 5.7 safe when i upgrade to 8.0? @user535733

Comment: They are if you back them up first. If not, then no promises.

Answer (score 2):

This is a cosmetic warning essentially complaining that a script is using the `apt-key` command and that in the future the command might change so scripts shouldn't be using it since it's designed for humans to use.

Comment: how should i do?

Comment: Follow the steps in the [MySQL Quick Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-upgrading) - All you have done is installed a package that adds the MySQL repositories, not actually installed or upgraded the `mysql-server` package(s) itself.

Comment: ...which means you still have the opportunity to backup your databases before doing the upgrade.